# C# LINQ First() faster than ToArray()[0]?

Tags: c#, linq

I am running a test.

It looks like:

method 1)

```
List<int> = new List<int>{1,2,4, .....} //assume 1000k
var  result ErrorCodes.Where(x => ReturnedErrorCodes.Contains(x)).First();
```

method 2)

```
List<int> = new List<int>{1,2,4, .....} //assume 1000k
var  result = ErrorCodes.Where(x => ReturnedErrorCodes.Contains(x)).ToArray()[0];
```

Why is method 2 is so slow compared to method 1?

Comment: What's the point of converting to an array anyway?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Erm... because you are creating an extra array (rather than just using the iterator). The first approach stops after the first match (`Where` is a non-buffered streaming API). The second loads ***all*** the matches into an array (presumably with several re-sizes), then takes the first item.

As a side note; you can create infinite sequences; the first approach would still work, the second would run forever (or explode).

It could also be:

```
var  result ErrorCodes.First(x => ReturnedErrorCodes.Contains(x));
```

(that won't make it any faster, but is perhaps easier to read)

Comment: The second approach would definitely explode if run on an infinite series; it'll get to sizeof(T) * array.Length > int.MaxValue and throw an OutOfMemoryException. No running forever about it.

Comment: @KeithS - that depends on whether the infinite sequence are all excluded by the `Where`, so that becomes never-ending but never-yielding. Or indeed, any *sane* finite number of matches and an infinite number of "misses".

Comment: To make the query even more readable, I'd suggest:
var result = ErrorCodes.First(ReturnedErrorCodes.Contains);

Comment: What would have been the case if the array (or other collection, lets say list), has already been created? would there be any performance changes?

Answer (score 62):

You have a jar containing a thousand coins, many of which are dimes. You want a dime. Here are two methods for solving your problem:

1. Pull coins out of the jar, one at a time, until you get a dime. Now you've got a dime.
2. Pull coins out of the jar, one at a time, putting the dimes in another jar. If that jar turns out to be too small, move them, one at a time, to a larger jar. Keep on doing that until you have all of the dimes in the final jar. That jar is probably too big.  Manufacture a jar that is exactly big enough to hold that many dimes, and then move the dimes, one at a time, to the new jar. Now start taking dimes out of that jar. Take out the first one. Now you've got a dime.

Is it now clear why method 1 is a whole lot faster than method 2?

Comment: OK, awesome analogy to run through that (but wouldn't the resizes use block-copy? not that this would change the performance profile at all ;p)

Comment: @Marc: The original code uses ints, which on 32 bit architectures, is the unit of atomicity. Copying a block of ints still just copies them one at a time when you get right down to it; it's just that the overhead per move is really low. On a 64 bit architecture the block copy does in fact move them over two at a time, which is even better. But still, the point is that huge amounts of memory are being copied unnecessarily if all that you want to do is find the first item.

Comment: @Eric - fair enough ;p Maybe it was hope-over-reality, but I somehow expected that anything getting down to something akin to BlockCopy would work at larger chunk sizes. My bad.

Comment: @Marc: Sadly, the hardware is what you get. There are of course really sneaky tricks to "copy" entire pages around; for example, tell the operating system to map the same hunk of physical memory to two different places in an address space; by doing so you appear to instantaneously "copy" from one buffer to another but in fact it is just two different "views" on the same physical storage.

Comment: Are there not SSE registers that would let you copy 128 (or soon 256) bits about at once? Not that it changes the core point of course, but just out of interest...

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: Sure, I suppose so. I actually know very little about what tricks the jitter uses to do this sort of thing.

Comment: I am trying to compare 2 huge result set in memory but getting memory exception.Can you please help me with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583201/compare-2-unordered-recordset-in-memory

Answer (score 4):

Because of deferred execution.

The code `ErrorCodes.Where(x => ReturnedErrorCodes.Contains(x))` doesn't return a collection of integers, instead it returns an expression that is capable of returning a stream of integers. It doesn't do any actual work until you start reading integers from it.

The `ToArray` method will consume the entire stream and put all the integers in an array. This means that every item in the entire list has to be compared to the error codes.

The `First` method on the other hand will only get the first item from the stream, and then stop reading from the stream. This will make it a lot faster, because it will stop comparing items from the list to the error codes as soon as it finds a match.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ToArray()` copies the entire sequence to an array.

Method 2 has to iterate over the whole sequence to build an array, and then returns the first element.

Method 1 just iterates over enough of the sequence to find the first matching element.

Answer (score 1):

`ToArray()` walks through the whole sequence it has been given and creates and array out of it.

If you don't callt `ToArray()`, `First()` lets `Where()` return just the first item that matches and immediatelly returns.

Answer (score 1):

First() is complexity of O(1)

ToArray()[0] is complexity O(n)+1

Comment: -1. This is not correct. Both are complexity O(n*m), where *n* is the number of items in the integer list and *m* is the number of items in the error codes list. The complexity doesn't say anything about their relative performance, only how they react to changed conditions.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, @Guffa - If you use First() and not First(predicate) the first item will always mach, therefore complexity of O(1). The ToArray() Will go over the whole List, therefore complexity of O(n).

Comment: true; I phrased it poorly - I meant in combination with Where(predicate).First(), as per the question

Comment: Yes, using only First() is O(1), but that's irrelevant to this question. So, either your answer is wrong, or irrelevant. Have your pick. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var @e = array.GetEnumerator();

// First
@e.MoveNext();
return @e.Current;

// ToArray (with yield [0] should as fast as First...)
while (@e.MoveNext() {
    yield return @e.Current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second example, you are actually converting the `IEnumerable<T>` to an array, whereas in the first example, no conversion is taking place.

Comment: The important bit is not that it is doing *some* conversion, but what that conversion actually does.

Answer (score 0):

In method 2 the entire array must be converted to an array first. Also, it seems awkward to mix array access when `First()` is so much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense, ToArray probably involves a copy, which is always going to be more expensive, since Linq can't make any guarantees about how you're going to use your array, while First() can just return the single element at the beginning.