# difference between linq.first() vs array[0]

Tags: c#

I am wondering what happens under the hood of list.first() and list[0] and which performs better.

For example which is faster?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 999999999999... i++)
{
    str.Split(';').First() vs. str.Split(';')[0]

    list.Where(x => x > 1).First() vs. list.Where(x => x > 1).ToList()[0]
}
```

Sorry In case of a duplicate question

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: `list.Where(x => x > 1).First()` vs `list.Where(x => x > 1).ToList()[0]` first solution has better pefromance - the second one will enumerate whole sequence while first solution will stop at first element.

Comment: Why not try it? perform your own benchmark, I'm not completely sure of the underlying difference but I would imagine `First()` is deferred execution

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/bc8ae402a61dd9d6.html

Comment: @Marwie - Thats not a complete duplicate since it doesn't answer the first comparison

Comment: thanks for referencesource link

Comment: @Sayse which first comparison? The expression is practically the same - does it make a difference if it is converted to a List or to an array?

Comment: @Marwie - It makes every difference since you are adding a conversion operation

Comment: @Sayse you are right - removed the note.

Comment: @Marwie - It was an ok note as a reference link, I just wanted to point out that it was incomplete

Comment: For the second comparison line reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064800/c-sharp-linq-first-faster-than-toarray0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which performs better? The array accessor, since that doesn't need a method to be put on the stack and doesn't have to execute the `First` method to *eventually* get to the array accessor.

As the [Reference Source of `Enumerable`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) shows, `First()` is actually:

```
IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
if (list != null) {
    if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
}
```

So it doesn't do anything else, it just takes more steps to get there.

For your second part (`list.Where(x => x > 1).First()` vs. `list.Where(x => x > 1).ToList()[0]`):

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, which isn't `IList` so it doesn't go for the first part of the `First` method but the second part:

```
using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (e.MoveNext()) return e.Current;
}
```

This will traverse each item one by one until it gets the desired index. In this case `0`, so it will get there *very* soon. The other one calling `ToList` will always be less efficient since it has to create a new object and put all items in there in order to get the first one. The first call is definitely faster.

Comment: @PatrickHofman `.First vs .ToList()[0]`

Comment: @Rawling see my comment or open Marwie link.

Answer (score 7):

Simple compaction of performance http://pastebin.com/bScgyDaM

```
str.Split(';').First(); :                        529103
str.Split(';')[0]; :                             246753
list.Where(x => x == "a").First(); :              98590
list.Where(x => x == "a").ToList()[0]; :         230858
```

First vs [0] 
if you have simple array faster is [0] because it only calculating adders in memory. 
but if you combine with others LINQ command faster is First(). for example Where().First() searching until he finds first element. Where().ToList()[0] finds all elements then convert to list and do a simple calculation.

another thing is that Where() is an deferred method.  A query that contains only deferred methods is not executed until the items in the result are enumerated.
so you can

```
list.Where( x => x>12);
list.add(10);
list.add(13);
foreach (int item in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item); 
}
```

13 will attach to result but 10 no because 10 and 13 were first added to the list later list was searched.

If you want to know more about Linq you can read that book Pro LINQ by  Joseph Rattz and Adam Freeman http://www.apress.com/9781430226536

Answer (score 1):

- `list.Where(x => x > 1).First() vs. list.Where(x => x > 1).ToList()[0]`

  The First() should be faster when applied to Enumerable because of
  deferred execution. In your case, the result will be returned as soon
  as one item of your list has been found that match the criteria
  *Where(x => x > 1)*.

  In the second example, your initial list has to be fully enumerated,
  **ALL** items matching the criteria will be put in a temporary list, of which you get the first item with the array accessor.
- `str.Split(';').First() vs. str.Split(';')[0]`

  In that case the method Split() already returns an array. The array accessor might be marginally faster, but the performance gain will be negligible in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant difference between these, you will get pretty much the same results:

```
 str.Split(';').First() vs. str.Split(';')[0]
```

For your second comparison, here you are asking only the first element

```
list.Where(x => x > 1).First()
```

So as soon as `WhereIterator` returns an item it's done. But in second you are putting all results into list then getting the first item using indexer , therefore it will be slower.