# Compare 2 unordered recordset in memory

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, linq, ado.net

Below is my application database table which contains SQL queries stored in a table: **QueryStorage**

```
Id           Query           ConnectionString       Rdbms
1            select...        Data Source           Sql Server
2            select...        Data Source           Oracle
```

The SQL queries in the above table are updated through web service and we are not allowed to update above the queries, though we can add something on top of the query something like this:

**Query stored in table:** `select id as LinkedColumn, Amount as CompareColumn from Source`

**Tweaked query from my c# app:**`select Q.LinkedColumn, Q.CompareColumn from (stored sql query) as Q`

I am trying to compare 2 unordered list like below:

Query executed for `Id = 1(Sql server)` from **QueryStorage table** records are like below:

```
select Id as LinkedColumn,CompareColumn from Source
```

**List 1:**

```
LinkedColumn     CompareColumn
1                100
2                200
3                300
4                400
5                500
6                600
7                700
8                800
9                900
10               1000
```

Query executed for `Id = 2(Oracle)` from **QueryStorage** table records are like below:

```
select Id as LinkedColumn,CompareColumn from Target
```

**List 2:**

```
LinkedColumn       CompareColumn
10                 10
9                  20
8                  30
7                  40
6                  50
5                  60
4                  70
3                  80
2                  90
1                  5
```

I want to join on `LinkedColumn from source to target` and then do comparison on `CompareColumn` which should give me following output:

```
SrcLinkedColumn      SrcCompareColumn     TgtLinkedColumn    TgtCompareColumn
    1                       100           1                  5
    2                       200           2                  90
```

Logic:

```
var data = (from s in List1.AsEnumerable()
             join t in List2.AsEnumerable() on s.Field<string>("LinkedColumn") equals t.Field<string>("LinkedColumn")
             where s.Field<decimal>("CompareColumn") != t.Field<decimal>("CompareColumn")
                        select new
                        {
                            srcLinkedcol = s.Field<string>("LinkedColumn"),
                            srcCompareCol = s.Field<decimal>("CompareColumn"),
                            tgtLinkedCol = t.Field<string>("LinkedColumn"),
                            tgtCompareCol = t.Field<decimal>("CompareColumn")
                        }).ToList();
```

There will be millions of records from source to target which I want to compare with so big issue is of `out of memory exception` which we are facing right now by loading all data in memory and then doing comparison with above linq query.

There are 2 solutions which I have thought of like below:

1) Open 2 ordered data reader.

Pros :

```
    - No memory exception
    - Fast as there will be 1 to 1 comparision of LinkedColumn for List1 and 
      List2 records.
```

Cons :

```
    - Order by is require on LinkedColumns and as i have no control over 
      query as because it is dumped by webservice in QueryStorage table so 
      user is explicitly require to submit query with order by on 
      LinkedColumn.
    - Wont work if order by on Linkedcolumn is not present.
    - Order by query have performance overhead so because of this user may not include order by on LinkedColumn in query.
```

2) Compare chunk by chunk records by tweaking query and adding `OffSet and FetchRowNext`. This is how I am thinking for algorithm:

[image]

But i still feel that with second approach i can get memory exception issue because at some steps where data from source and target are not matching i will be storing them inside buffer(datatable or list etc..) for next chunk comparision.

Can anybody please guide me what should be the good algorithm for this or any better way to address this?

**Note :** I dont want to use **LinkedServer** and **SSIS**.

Answer (score 5):

Your second solution looks like an attempt to re-invent the [External merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). It is a valid approach if your data doesn't fit into memory, but it is overkill when your datasets fit into memory.

24 million rows with two numbers each (8 bytes) is only ~200MB of memory.
Two datasets are 400MB. This is nothing on the modern desktop hardware.

Load both datasets in memory. In simple arrays. Sort arrays in memory. 
Find the difference by scanning both sorted arrays once.
You don't need fancy LINQ for that.

Here is pseudocode. We have `Array1` and `Array2`. Maintain two variables that contain the current index of each array: `Idx1` and `Idx2`. Move the indexes along the arrays looking for places where `LinkedColumn` match.

```cs
Idx1 = 0; Idx2 = 0;
while (true)
{
    // scan arrays until both indexes point to the same LinkedColumn
    // here we assume that both arrays are sorted by LinkedColumn
    // and that values in LinkedColumn are unique

    while (Idx1 < Array1.Length && Idx2 < Array2.Length &&
        Array1[Idx1].LinkedColumn < Array2[Idx2].LinkedColumn)
    {
        // move along Array1
        Idx1++;
    }

    while (Idx1 < Array1.Length && Idx2 < Array2.Length &&
        Array1[Idx1].LinkedColumn > Array2[Idx2].LinkedColumn)
    {
        // move along Array2
        Idx2++;
    }

    // at this point both indexes point to the same LinkedColumn
    // or one or both of the arrays are over

    if (Idx1 >= Array1.Length || Idx2 >= Array2.Length)
    {
        break;
    }

    // compare the values
    if (Array1[Idx1].CompareColumn != Array2[Idx2].CompareColumn)
    {
        // TODO: output/save/print the difference
    }

    Idx1++; Idx2++;
}
```

### OR

you can dump both datasets in a database of your choice in two tables `T1` and `T2`, create unique index on `LinkedColumn` in both tables and run this query:

```sql
SELECT
     T1.LinkedColumn  AS SrcLinkedColumn
    ,T1.CompareColumn AS SrcCompareColumn
    ,T2.LinkedColumn  AS DstLinkedColumn
    ,T2.CompareColumn AS DstCompareColumn
FROM
    T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.LinkedColumn = T2.LinkedColumn
WHERE
    T1.CompareColumn <> T2.CompareColumn
ORDER BY
    T1.LinkedColumn
;
```

The pseudocode above performs the same merge join as the DBMS server would perform for this query.

Comment: I am getting out of memory exception when i am trying to load this 12 millions records in array and list too.

Comment: @User, 12 * 8 = 96 million bytes. It is hard to believe that your computer doesn't have 100MB of free memory. I'd recommend you to ask another question specifically about loading this data in memory. Show there your code and somebody would be able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @User, I'm saying here 8 bytes per record, because your sample data in the question is simple integers. If your actual data is different, then please update the question and tell us what it is.

Comment: @User VladimirBaranov is correct, you should able to load that data with no issues. Unless you have a hardware bottle neck. Make sure that you have at least 2GB of free memory. And from your VS go to the project properties and on the Build make sure your platform target is set to x64

Comment: @User I still prefer to use the database engine over C# to maintain the queries. So, the second suggestion that Vladimir Baranov is much preferable (in my opinion).

Comment: What if i have 9-10 task like this then dont you think this will require huge memory or can crash memory if system doesnt have that much memory?

Comment: @User, it is very easy to calculate how much memory you need. Just multiply the size of each element of the array by the number of elements. If your program uses much more memory than this estimate, then there is something wrong with the program. Once you know how much memory the task needs, you'll know if your computer has enough memory for this task. My estimate was 200MB. For 10 tasks it would be 2GB. It is not uncommon to have 16GB of memory in modern laptops. You can easily have hundreds of GB of memory in the server.

Comment: @User, if you estimate that you need terabytes of memory, then you'll have to start looking for a different algorithm, but so far your data sets don't look so big. Essentially, you'll need something like [External sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). External sorting is a class of sorting algorithms that can handle massive amounts of data. External sorting is required when the data being sorted do not fit into the main memory of a computing device (usually RAM) and instead they must reside in the slower external memory, usually a hard disk drive.

Comment: @User, in your second solution in the question it looks like you were trying to re-invent the External merge sort.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you get tables data in `C#` by somethings like `DataReader`. If you store records that fetch from web service and then execute some query as @VladimirBaranov mentioned, it need too long time for storing and it not reasonable.

I think a better solution for comparing in this case is [**Binary Search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Time order of it is `O(log n)` and Memory order of it is O(1). So it doesn't need to extra memory.

You can use Binary search like below:

**1- Sorting smaller table.**

*Time order*: If this table has n element, on average, executing time is `O(nlogn)` ([more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)).

*Memory order*: O(1), because `sort` method in C# is [**In-place**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).

**2- Comparing another table records with sorted table by Binary search.**

*Time order*: If another table has m records, executing time is `O(m)*O(logn) = O(mlogn)`.
([more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2))

*Memory order*: It needs no extra memory.

To conclusion, I thank may be best solution for your issue, but I think this solution is good solution that has `O(mlogn)` executing time, `O(1)` memory order and it implements only in C#, no need to save records in database.

Comment: So if i talk about your 2nd approach then for that do i need to bring 2 result set in memory and then compare?

Comment: For comparing, you need to bring both of them in memory, but by my solution, extra memory that you need is `O(1)`. Other solutions like @VladimirBaranov  need O(n*m) extra memory.

Comment: But if i will have multiple jobs running in parallel lets say like 8-10 jobs and with each jobs will be working with 24 millions data so you can imagine the amount of data there will be in memory in case of 8-10 jobs or more than that sometimes so how does memory will gonna cope up with that data?

Comment: It's clear. Your data is close to [Big data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data). All of algorithms have many challenges in that case. You need to more powerful server for doing it. All of algorithms like my algorithm can optimize memory or executing time as possible as and they can't handle every situations.

Answer (score 1):

You probably get a out of memory due to a memory fragmentation.

- Ensure that you use an efficient way to read your data like a DataReader.
- To avoid fragmentation, get the count of your records and initialize the List 1 array with this count before starting to insert in the array. If you cannot get the count you can increase the grow factor of your list or build a query that will contains the original query as a sub query like this: 
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( [YOUR ORIGINAL QUERY HERE] )
- Build an array of struct that contains your fields or a 2 dimensions array, this will not require a reference for each rows.
- Also, you can store the original (List 1) data in your destination format. This way you will only have one array in memory.

Here is the pseudo code:

- Get row count of List1:
- Create a 2 dimensions array to hold data of list1
- Get data from List1 and add those record to your array
- Dispose you first datareader
- Use an in place sort to sort list1 data (this way you will be able to use binary search to find list1 row).
- Get data from List2
- Foreach row of List2 use a binary search to find corresponding record in list1: Add compare value of List2 to the matching row (remember your array already contains your 3 columns). You only need to set the compare value of list2).
- Cleanup you result by removing rows that do not have match. I recommend you to cleanup using the same array. With two index you can scan you array and move up record in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I can only give you an idea :

Constraints :

- Target has millions of records
- Source has millions of records
- Memory is limited

The idea :

1. Use at least 2 machines for this
2. One as the [Source], and the other one as the [Target] which has the matching service
3. Send every n (chunk) records from [Source] to [Target] machine by calling the service, let it match the records and then send back the result to [Source]

Bonus :

4. Use more than 1 [Target] machines, and let the [Source] machine utilize them all in asynchronous and load balanced scenario

There are some similar (or advance) solutions you may find, like :

- [Target] and [Source] may utilize a shared memory (a cache server, for example) to store the result
- using a real load-balancer layer between them, to handle multiple requests to multiple [Target] machines
- using a queue/messaging layer
- even using multiple [Source] with multiple [Target] machines

I'm sorry but (at least for me) this case is too big too handle by using 1 machine only

I hope at least this could give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

As it seems `LinkedColumn` contains unique values **on each source**, I would load both data in two tables in a local database, create an index on `LinkedColumn` and do a join.

Or you can load both data in a simple file, including a source identifier on each row as follows (don't include the header):

```
LinkedColumn   Identifier   CompareColumn
1              S            100
2              S            200
3              S            300
                   ...
4              O            70
3              O            80
2              O            90
```

*S stands for SQL Server and O for Oracle.* Sort the file (maybe you can run the OS sort or another external sort). Read the sorted file line by line. The first line must be stored so you'll compare its `LinkedColumn` with the second line for a match, thus collecting them or storing the second one and dropping the first to look for a match on the third and so on.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the elements that match? Something like:

```
List1.RemoveAll(x => List2.Any(y => y.LinkedColumn == x.LinkedColumn && y.CompareColumn == x.CompareColumn))
```

Comment: I have 24 millions records in my source and target.This will throw memory exception as i have tested

Comment: What about if you load the same range of LinkedColumn from source and destination... select Id as LinkedColumn,CompareColumn from Source where  LinkedColumn >=1 and LinkedColumn <=1000 (using a sensible range) and the same range from Target. Loop until you get to the max LinkedColumn?

Answer (score 0):

Just leave this job to SQL Server.

Let it process WHERE CLAUSE

`T1.CompareColumn <> T2.CompareColumn`

Comment: Best practice! Its the fastest way.

Comment: What if data for source are coming from Sql server and target data are coming from Oracle then tell me how this will gonna work?

Comment: I have already mentioned that in my question that my source data is coming from sql server and target is coming from oracle