# The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation error with 1000 seconds

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection-pooling, datareader, connection-timeout

I have 24 millions records in source(12 millions) and target(12 millions) and i am trying to compare records between source and target.

**Error :**

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation

When i run my `Test method` for `once` then it is working fine but when i have running it in parallel(`thrice`) then i am getting above error.

I can increase timeout to some more but i have read that it is really bad design and bad idea to increase timeout.

I am failing to understand the reason behind this that how it is working fine with calling `Test method once` and `why it is failing when it is called thrice`.

With this i am trying to test amount of load database server can handle if i am submiting lots of jobs of comparision like below :

**Code :**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Task<string>[] taskArray = { Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>Test()),
                                     Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => Test()),
                                     Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => Test())
            };
        }


 public static string Test()
 {
   var srcConnection = new SqlConnection("SourceConnectionString");
   srcConnection.Open();
   var command1 = new SqlCommand("Source Sql Query", srcConnection);
   var tgtConnection = new SqlConnection("TargetConnectionString");
   tgtConnection.Open();
   var command2 = new SqlCommand("Target Sql Query", tgtConnection);
   var drA = GetReader(srcConnection, command1);
   var drB = GetReader(tgtConnection, command2);
   bool moreA = drA.Read();
   bool moreB = drB.Read();
   while (moreA && moreB)
    {
       //my logic for 1 - 1 record comparision in case of ordered record on Primary key on source and          target.
    }
 }

 private static IDataReader GetReader(SqlConnection con, SqlCommand command)
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
            return command.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

I am failing to understand that though i have set timeout to be 1000 seconds why it is failing.

```
 Task<string>[] taskArray = { Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => Test())//Works fine

 Task<string>[] taskArray = { Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>Test()),
                                     Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => Test()),
                                     Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => Test())
            };//Timeout Error
```

**Source Query :** `select Id as LinkedColumn,CompareColumn from Source`

**Target Query :** `select Id as LinkedColumn,CompareColumn from Target`

**Source Query Execution time in Sql server management studio for 12377200 records:** 
 00:02:10

**Target Query Execution time in Sql server management studio for 12266800 records:** 
 00:03:37

What would be the best way to handle this scenario considering what i am trying to do?

Comment: Can you give us the exact use case to understand the scenario more clearly? Because i can sense a huge database operation here which needs to be done in database itself using a stored procedure or some other logic instead of using code to just pull data and comparing it in application layer

Comment: You do realize that running your `test` method 3 times means selecting all the records from both databases 3 times? No wonder you get a timeout...

Comment: @ZoharPeled So if i have several jobs like this which i want to run in parallel which are again dealing with comparing millions of records and i dont want to overflow memory(hence using data reader) so there is no way to do this data reader?

Comment: @Sivaprasath You can get my use case from this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583201/compare-2-unordered-recordset-in-memory

Comment: You don't get that putting a load on database server will slow it down?

Comment: @Paparazzi But database is basically designed to handle this much amount of load.Isnt it?

Comment: So how long does it take for 1 query (which does not fail by timeout)?

Comment: @User Evidently not

Comment: Why downvote?Whats wrong with this question?I dont think its a duplicate and i dont think i have failed to explain this question properly.I wish downvoters atleast care to comment whats wrong with this question so next time i will know what to do and what not to :)

Comment: @Evk when i call Test methods once then this whole approach takes around 5 minutes or something so that means query would execute in around 3-4 minutes though i will update you with exact figures.Right now i have set commandtimeout to 0(infinity) with 3 methods running in parallel.I have not got any error uptill now because still it is running.Once it is completed i will show you exact figure for query.Thanks :)

Comment: @mjwills It is very very very simple query.Let me update it in my question

Comment: @mjwillsIt is 12 Compute Cores 4C+8G 3.60 GHz.Moreover i updated my question to include sql queries

Comment: @Evk I am also looking for the best way to do what i am doing.Do you think i am doing in a right way?

Comment: General approach (read records one by one and compare) looks fine to me. Of course you need to dispose all stuff (data reader, connection etc), but that's not relevant to general approach. I don't see why doing this 3 times in parallel should take much more time (of course it might take a bit more time, but not 3 times slower for example). Worth looking at exact times it takes to run 1 and 3 in parallel.

Comment: With 12377200 records in source and 12266800 records in target,time it took 4:01 seconds for the first time when i tested with 1 method.After that it took 6 minutes with again 1 method.Now i am running 3 methods in parallel but still it is running and i guess it has been more than 15 minutes still i havent got output of 1 method

Comment: Maybe you are bounded by your network capacity? You may want to monitor your network usage during 1 and 3 tests and see if it's capped.

Comment: @Evk I updated my question in which i have mention the duration for each sql query running time in sql server management studio

Comment: Yes, but what about network usage? Maybe you have say 10MB\s network and transfering data of one query takes 8MB\s of bandwidth. Unlikely, but who knows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164967/discussion-between-user-and-evk).